# Add a Maven Project as a depdendency to a Java Web Project in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ant

I have an existing Java / Maven project, which does not have an ANT build script.
I would like to use this project as a dependency in a Java Web Project in NetBeans.
When I try to add the project, as a library, I get the message:

"This project cannot be added because it does not produce a JAR file using an Ant script."

I can obviously output a JAR and link that in, but I would like Netbeans to ensure that when I build my Web project, my dependent project also gets built if necessary.

Maybe there is some Ant wrapper for maven?

To be clear this is a *java web project (not maven)* which depends on a *java project (with maven)*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a plugin for maven to do this.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ant-plugin/index.html

Answer (score -1):

You should add the maven project's local repository jar as the Ant project dependency. You will have to build each project separately but apart from that things should be working fine.

Comment: Agreed. The point is that is a hassle. If I have 20 projects, remembering when to build which one is precisely the kind of donkey work I expect the IDE/build system to do for me.

Comment: Well, ant projects in netbeans don't handle the "donkey work" as it's apparently non-mainstream and your only option to add the dependency as jar, rather than library (or project dep). If you decide to add it as jar dependency, then the jar location outlined in the answer is the optimal location to use (as it will at least in the IDE do the hard inter-project connections work for you, like hyperlinks, editor compilation will happen against the sources of the maven projects etc)

Comment: and if you have 20 projects like this, you you not be mixing 2 build systems in the first place.